# how fetch data from database through api using axios in reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, restify

I have develope application in reactjs and nodejs with postgresql database, when i call api using axios from AxiosTable.js file data from table is fetched successfully and displayed in console but when i try to display in table it doesnot work, so tell me what i do wrong here?

**server.js**

```
    var restify=require('restify')
    const {empdetails} = require('./Function');
    var server=restify.createServer() //server created

    
    
    server.get('/empdetails',empdetails)
    
    server.listen(8080, function(){
        console.log("server started...")
    })
```

**AxiosTable.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'
    export class AxiosTable extends Component {
        state={
            persons:[]
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/empdetails')
          .then(res => {
            const persons = res.data;
            this.setState({ persons });
          })
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="App">
                <div className="left">
                <table className="table table-hover table-dark">
                 <tr>
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Email</th>
                   
                 </tr>
                 { this.state.persons.map(person => 
                   <tr>
                     <td>{person.id}</td>
                     <td>{person.name}</td>
                     <td>{person.email}</td>
                     
                     
                     </tr>
                   )}
                 </table>
               </div>    </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default AxiosTable
```

**Function.js** //backend code

```
var Sequelize=require('sequelize')
 
const connection = new Sequelize('mydb', 'postgres', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect:  'postgres' 
  });

  var Demo=connection.define('demo',{
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }    
})

module.exports ={

    
// employee details fetched
    empdetails: function empdetails(req,res,next){
        res.send('employee details ')
        connection.sync().then(function(){
            Demo.findAll().then(function(demos){
                          console.log(demos)
              })
          })
    },
 };
```

Comment: Add `console.log(this.state);` before the `return` in your render function and look in your browser's developer console to see the state being attempted to render.

Comment: it show
{persons: Array(0)}

Comment: Right. That means there are no persons to render in your table :)

Comment: but when i run this AxiosTable.js that time data from database is displayed in backend code console

Comment: Can you also console.log(persons) before setState in componentDidMount

Comment: @PrathameshJadhav Then your backend doesn't pass them properly to the frontend - from the `console.log()` you can plainly see there are no persons to show. Show us the backend code too?

Comment: @AKX lets see now i have added backend code (function.js)

Comment: @PrathameshJadhav Well, yeah, your backend code sends `employee details` down the wire and just logs stuff, it doesn't send any employee data.

Comment: @AKX then how i can getdata?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 componentDidMount(){
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/empdetails')
          .then(res => {
            const persons = res.data;
            this.setState(prevState => { persons: [...prevState.persons, persons] });
          })
        }
```

Comment: You're overring the state, so you have to use the spread operator to get the actual state, and add the new one. Hope it works

Comment: this.setState(prevState => { persons: [...prevState.persons, persons] });


Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Answer (score 0):

Your backend is not actually returning any data, it looks like.

Try something like

```
function empdetails(req, res, next) {
  connection.sync().then(() => {
    Demo.findAll().then((demos) => {
      console.log(demos);
      res.send(demos);  // <-- This is the important bit! :)
    });
  });
}
```

instead.

Comment: this sends data on backend page (when function.js ) is executed

Comment: I'm not following you. Your original `empdetails` function, in your question, does not actually send the data it retrieves from the database; this does.